Guidance on how to assess the impact of multiple parallel SELECT queries
Setup: SQL Server 2019 on Azure VM.
We have an application that, on a specific date, will execute multiple queries to load data into their system. These queries will be run via Databricks using an ODBC connection, and they will primarily consist of SELECT statements with various joins and filters.
I'm looking for guidance on how to assess whether the workload generated by these queries could be problematic. Specifically, I want to understand what metrics I should monitor during this workload to evaluate its impact on server performance.
Key Questions:

How can I determine if the workload of their queries is causing issues? What signs should I look for?
How many queries can be run in parallel without negatively affecting server performance? Is there a way to calculate or estimate this?
What are the most important statistics to measure during the execution of these queries? How can I compare server performance during the workload against periods without workload?



How can I determine if the workload of their queries is causing issues?

Use a trace or performance analysis tools like sp_WhoIsActive.

What signs should I look for?

Long running queries (longer than usual), blocking, inordinary wait types.

How many queries can be run in parallel without negatively affecting server performance?

Unanswerable. Depends on the hardware provisioned to your server, how your server is configured, and what else is actively running on it.

Is there a way to calculate or estimate this?

Sure, trace your server while pushing it to the limit. Or a very similarly equivalent test server.

What are the most important statistics to measure during the execution of these queries?

Wait Stats are always useful to keep an eye on. As already mentioned earlier, also watch for blocking.

How can I compare server performance during the workload against periods without workload?

Use a tool to trace performance, as already mentioned.
